# XAMPP rename function

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a bulk rename in this way:

```
if ($handle = opendir('../../upload_files')) {
  while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
    $newName = str_replace(", ","_",$fileName);
    rename($fileName, $newName);
    $count++;
  }
  closedir($handle);
  echo $count." files renamed";
}
```

But when I run the script, I get a warning:

```
Warning: rename(..,..) [function.rename]: No error in E:\WEBS\rename.php on line 6
```

What is causing the error?

Comment: Perhaps you should try unlinking `unlink()` file first or copying `copy()` it. Such error usually comes up in windows environment. PHP5.3 is known for such error as I know. Check this bug out https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48771

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: @h4unt3r XAMPP is windows

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka There is also a linux distro of XAMPP available, so the question 'what platform are you on' could assist a little bit

Comment: XAMPP for Windows :-)

Comment: `E:\WEBS\rename.php` tells you that it is Windows

Comment: It's a php bug! Thanks Dachi, I check out just now.

Comment: look at my answer. I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

If the target file already exists, PHP is known for such error under Windows environment.

There's a known bug for PHP 5.3 https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48771 with similar error message.

I recommend trying out following modification of your code (it's based on your code, just with some corrections)

```
$dir = "../../upload_files";
if ($handle = opendir($dir))
{
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if (!isset($count)) $count = 0;
        if ($fileName == ".." || $fileName == ".") continue;
        $newName = str_replace(", ","_",$fileName);
        copy($dir.$fileName, $dir.$newName);
        $count++;
    }
    closedir($handle);
    echo $count." files renamed";
}
```